# Bind scope property to tab title

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and I am having trouble with binding properties of scope so two way binding can work properly. I am using sample code to generate tabs.

```
<div ng-app="SampleApp">
    <div id="tabs" ng-controller="GridController as gridcon">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}"
                ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mainView">
            <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="changedata()" value="Check" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my scope have two observable arrays and I want to show count of those arrays in tab title. I am using following code for controller.

```
var appRoot = angular.module('SampleApp', ["kendo.directives"]);

    appRoot.controller('GridController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.data1 = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
            {
                issueId: 1,
                issue: "County Incorrect"
            },
            {
                issueId: 2,
                issue: "City Incorrect"
            },
            {
                issueId: 3,
                issue: "Name Incorrect"
            }
        ]);

        $scope.data2 = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
            {
                "id": 11,
                "first_name": "James",
                "last_name": "Butt",
                "company_name": "Benton, John B Jr",
                "address": "6649 N Blue Gum St",
                "city": "New Orleans",
                "county": "Bridgepoort",
                "state": "LA",
                "zip": 70116,
                "phone1": "504-621-8927",
                "phone2": "504-845-1427",
                "email": "jbutt@gmail.com",
                "web": "http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "first_name": "Josephine",
                "last_name": "Darakjy",
                "company_name": "Chanay, Jeffrey A Esq",
                "address": "4 B Blue Ridge Blvd",
                "city": "Brighton",
                "county": "Livingston",
                "state": "MI",
                "zip": 48116,
                "phone1": "810-292-9388",
                "phone2": "810-374-9840",
                "email": "josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org",
                "web": "http://www.chanayjeffreyaesq.com"
            }
        ]);

        $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'Issue List (0)'.replace("0", $scope.data1.length),
            url: 'tab1.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Corrected (0)'.replace("0", $scope.data2.length),
            url: 'tab2.html'
        }];

        $scope.currentTab = 'tab1.html';

        $scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
            $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
        }

        $scope.isActiveTab = function (tabUrl) {
            return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
        }

        $scope.changedata = function () {
            $scope.data1.pop();
            $scope.data2.pop();
            console.log($scope.data1.length);
            console.log($scope.data2.length);
        }
    }]);
```

Now this works fine when you are loading page for first time. Now on a button click ("Check" button), I am modifying the arrays. What should I do so that tab title is always in sync with length of arrays ?  I have tried observable objects but unless I am using binding in view, they will just notify the event. Is there no other way except handling change event of observable arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  Copy this piece of code inside the  $scope.changedata function.

```
 $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'Issue List (0)'.replace("0", $scope.data1.length),
            url: 'tab1.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Corrected (0)'.replace("0", $scope.data2.length),
            url: 'tab2.html'
        }];
```

Also it remains outside as well.

Comment: What is use of data binding if I need to modify values myself ?

Comment: Please understand that you have not binded your data on to the view. You are just modifying a value using  JS.

Comment: Actually, I am ready to modify my view to make it binded. Any suggestions ?

Comment: then you can add one more property to your tabs like this            ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}({{tab.dataLength}})</li>      You will have to update the dataLength property in your changedata function. And stop replacing the string like you are doing currently.   Does this help?

Comment: Yup, lemme try this and I will update you once it is done. Thanks for your help )